# Initialize inline vector of bool

Tags: c++, vector, c++98

I am using this example to initialize the bool vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 map<int, vector<bool> > myMap;
 vector<bool> one {true, true, false};
 myMap[2] = one;
 cout << myMap[2][0] << endl;
 cout << myMap[2][1] << endl;
 cout << myMap[2][2] << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

The only change I made in this code is using `std::vector` instead of vector and I now have:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<bool> >  m_links;
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse {false, false, false, false, false};
```

It tells me to use `;` after `m_allFalse`. How can I get rid of this error?

I am using intel compiler 14, but without c++11.

Comment: `std::vector<bool> m_allFalse = {false, false, false, false, false};`

Comment: Did you compile with a C++11 compiler/give the necessary compiler options to compile as C++11?

Comment: Either compiles fine on gcc 4.9. Post a complete example that displays the error message, the exact error message, your compiler version and how you compile.

Comment: check update for generic initialization

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem is:

```
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse {false, false, false, false, false};
```

wrong syntax in standard C++. (maybe in C++11, I don't know)

You can use this instance:

```
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse(5, false); (*)
```

If you want C++11 edit your tag and follow @lakesh tip.

(*) this constructor is explained in vector [**documentation**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/):

> (2) fill constructor Constructs a container with n elements. Each
>   element is a copy of val.

To initialize general boolean values at the beginning, you can use this way:

```
bool tempBool[] = { true, false, false, true };
std::vector<bool> variousBool ( tempBool, tempBool + sizeof(tempBool) / sizeof(bool) );
```

Knowing this, you could create your own vector class, simply inheriting from vector (if you want you can use template to extend to all types):

```
class PimpedVector : public std::vector<bool>  {
public:
  PimpedVector(const unsigned int& size, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, size); 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
      bool b = va_arg(args, bool);
      this->push_back(b);
    }
  }
}
```

So from your main you can create a PimpedVector in this way:

```
PimpedVector p0(5, true, false, false, true, false);
```

Comment: It's definitely C++11 syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but I am compiling using c++98.

Comment: @celtschk you're right, but in tag there's not C++11.

Comment: The `std::vector<bool> m_allFalse(5, false);` method gives `error: expected a type specifier`

Comment: @www: From the variable name, I guess you're declaring a class member (a crucial detail which actually contradicts your question text because it means you've changed more than the vector initialization syntax). If so, the edit to my answer should help you.

Comment: take a look here for "expected a type specifier":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845117/error-expected-type-specifier-before-classname

Answer (score 6):

The feature you're using was introduced in C++11. Since, as your question edit reveals, you're compiling as C++98, the compiler rightfully complains about it, because it is not valid C++98 syntax.

For the special case of all values being the same, the C++98 way (still working in C++11, and for this special case preferred there, too) to initialize is, as mentioned by Velthune,

```
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse(5, false);
```

Actually since `std::vector` default-initializes all its values, and `false` is the default value of `bool`, for that specific case you can even simplify it to

```
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse(5);
```

If you want more general values, you'll have to copy them in, for example:

```
std::vector<bool> foo(3);
foo[0] = foo[1] = true;
foo[2] = false; // that line is actually not needed because of default initialization of members
```

or

```
std::vector<bool> foo;
foo.push_back(true);
foo.push_back(true);
foo.push_back(false); // this time, it is needed because it actually created the thirs argument
```

An additional note: I notice the `m_` prefix of your variable name; this suggests that you're declaring a *member* variable (if so, that's a crucial detail which you left out). A member variable cannot (in C++98) be given an initializer (of any sort) at its declaration (with the exception of static const members of integer type). For non-static member variables, you have to initialize them at the constructor call, for example:

```
class X
{
public:
  X(); // the constructor
private:
  std::vector<bool> m_Foo;
};

// constructor definition follows
X::X():
  m_Foo(5, false) // this initializes your member variable `m_Foo`
{
}
```

Comment: Then what is the solution to initialize boolean values in the beginning?

Comment: If all the values are the same, use the replacement given by Velthune. Otherwise the only thing you can do is to copy the data into the vector (either by individual push_back or assignment expressions, or by first defining a conventional array with those values and then using `std::copy` to get the values into the vector).