# cannot convert 'int*' to 'ABC*' in assignment

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I can't figure out this little compile error...

file.h

```
    #ifndef FILE_H
    #define FILE_H

    class ABC: public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ABC(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
        {       
    ..
        }
    ..
    };

    class BCD : public QDialog
    {
    ....

        ABC* m_abc;
    };
#endif
```

in file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
BCD::BCD()
{
  ....
    m_abc = new ABC::ABC(ui->frame);   /// line with errors
}
```

getting errors

```
expected type specifier
cannot convert 'int*' to 'ABC*' in assignment
expected ;
```

So i try to research to find causes of this error... and check possible issues... (like in this question [Error: expected type-specifier before 'ClassName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845117/error-expected-type-specifier-before-classname))

My include guards are fine, classes are set up fine, intellisense finds all symbols...

Changing line to

```
m_abc = new ::ABC::ABC(ui->frame);
```

results in the errors:

```
expected type specifier before :: token
cannot convert 'int*' to 'ABC*' in assignment
expected ; before '::' token
```

where can i find my error ?

Sorry I cannot list the entire code.

Comment: Maybe: `m_abc = new ABC(ui->frame);`?

Comment: Why not just `new ABC(ui->frame)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ABC::ABC(ui->frame)` should be `new ABC(ui->frame)`

You're calling the constructor wrong.

reason is ABC::ABC looks for the class ABC in the namespace ABC (which you probably don't have, therefore its defaulting to int) but if you use just ABC it will find ABC in the current namespace