# Expected type-specifier before 'QSslSocket' in QT Application

Tags: c++, qt, email

I am still fairly new to Qt, but I'd like to write a program that allows a user to send a small message via email.

When I go to build my project I get errors like
`expected type-specifier before 'QSslSocket'` and `'QSslSocket' was not declared in this scope`. I get these both when I try to compile my code and when I try to compile the demos from the git, so I don't think it is in my code.

Looking into this issue I have seen that most solutions involve making sure that openssl is installed on the machine and that Qt was built with the openssl flag set in the configuration. I have ensured that I have openssl and libssl-dev installed and I just rebuilt my version of Qt using the openssl flag. Still no luck.

In my project I have `QT += core network` added in my .pro file. I have `#include <QtNetwork/QsslSocket>` in my *.h file that requires it.

As for my system, I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have Qt 4.8.6 installed (again with -openssl included in the config file). Openssl and libssl-dev are both at 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11.

If you have any ideas they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The correct include line (you can find it in the docs) is `#include <QSslSocket>`.  Also, did you re-run qmake after adding `network` to your .pro file?

Comment: The project I was building off of used the `#include <QtNetwork/QSslSocket>` line originally. I tried again with `#include <QSslSocket>` instead and I still get the `QSslSocket does not name a type` error.  On the 2nd part, I'm using QtCreator and hitting build. I was assuming that was running qmake as part of it's process. Is it not? I've successfully built and run projects this way, just not ones involving ssl.

Comment: If you chance the .pro file manually, you have to right click on the project and click "Run qmake".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: expected type-specifier before 'ClassName'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845117/error-expected-type-specifier-before-classname). Interestingly, they are using Qt, too.

Comment: You can probably remove the paragraph that starts with: *"Looking into this issue I have seen that most solutions involve making sure that openssl...:*. It has nothing to do with the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it did come down to my configuration. I completely removed all versions of Qt4 off my computer`sudo make uninstall` (since I installed from a tarball instead of from the repository), I cleaned my configuration file using `make confclean`, I rebuilt the configuration using `./configure -openssl`, then `make` and finally `sudo make install`. I think the issue before was that I had not cleaned my config file first. I had a version installed for embedded Linux and it is possible that I was applying the `-openssl` flag to that build since I had installed that later. For the record both `#include <QtNetwork/QSslSocket>` and `#include <QSslSocket>` work, at least in my version of Qt (4.8.6).